# EC2 instance not joining ECS Cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I have an EC2 cluster and I'm trying to add EC2 machines to it.

I have added `ECS_CLUSTER=cluster_name` to `/etc/ecs/ecs.config` with *user data* but the instance doesn't join the cluster.

I'm looking for log files or any other evidence of the cluster-joining process that may indicate why my instance is not joining.  I do not have a `/var/log/ecs` folder.

Comment: It's possible for this to happen as a result of your EC2 instances being rate limited by DockerHub.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use an ECS AMI,

Or you need to install the ECS agent

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-agent-install.html

And then you need to start/restart the ecs agent after changing that config

```
restart ecs
```

Comment: aha, I don't have the ecs service.  Looks like I need to pick a particular AMI http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-optimized_AMI.html

Comment: Now that I'm using the ECS AMI I have the service and can view logs in ```/var/log/ecs```

Comment: Beware that the user data is only run the first time the instance is run, so if you update your user data it won't re-add ECS_CLUSTER to /etc/ecs/ecs.config after the first time it is booted.

Comment: Look inside `/var/log/ecs/ecs-agent.lg` is super helpful. My case is IAM role has no enough permission.

Answer (score 3):

Restart ECS does not fix the issue.

In my case i check logs under

```
/var/logs/ecs

tail -f ecs-agent.log.2018-09-05-15
```

So I notice

```
2018-09-05T15:26:22Z [ERROR] Could not register: NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain. Deprecated.
    For verbose messaging see aws.Config.CredentialsChainVerboseErrors
```

Just Assign ECS role and instance registered with the cluster.

Maybe this answer helps some.

Answer (score 1):

**Symptom of problem:**

You have an ECS cluster with a capacity provider that is successfully provisioning EC2 instances. However, your ECS cluster shows "Container instances" as an empty list, indicating the provisioned EC2 instances are not being attached to the cluster. You have also made sure that your launch template has "user data" defined on it with a bash script similar to the following (replacing variables appropriately):

```
#!/bin/bash

## Configure cluster name using the template variable ${ecs_cluster_name}

echo ECS_CLUSTER='${ecs_cluster_name}' >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config
```

**Reason for problem:**

You have EC2s. The EC2s have a launch script. However, the EC2s are not using an AMI with an ECS agent installed and running that will interpret `/etc/ecs/ecs.config` and then attach itself to the appropriate cluster.

**Solution:**

1. Use an ECS-optimized AMI for your launch definition instead of a regular AMI. Here is a list of recommended AMIs from Amazon: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-optimized_AMI.html
2. If you already had an EC2 running prior to the above change, then terminate the existing EC2; alternately go to your capacity provider and perform an "instance refresh" operation.
3. Now observe that the "Container instances" list should no longer be empty.

Answer (score 0):

Same deal here except mine was related to a configuration option I found while setting up my first cluster. I specified propagate tags from the ec2 instance which I had found here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/launch_container_instance.html

```
# ecs.config
ECS_CONTAINER_INSTANCE_PROPAGATE_TAGS_FROM=ec2_instance`
```

The log output suggested my EC2 environment variables for ECS were asking for a new feature set: `Error registering: InvalidParameterException: Long arn format must be enabled for tagging.`

After some Googling I found the issue as described here: https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/10762#issue-518401992

### Solution

You need to either configure a specific user scope or preform the action as root.

1. Go into your web console as root.
2. Head over to ECS
3. Select `Account Settings` in the left hand nav pane.
4. Enable the newer arn format options. In my case I enabled all of them.

[image]

5. Log out, sign in as a non root user and reboot your ec2 instances.